# How to find which groups have identical values in a specific column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table that contains letters and numbers:

```
xx <- tibble (letter = c (rep ("a", 3), rep ("b", 3), rep ("c", 3)),
              number = c (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

I would like to first group data by "letter" and then check if there are any two groups that have identical values in number column. These would be groups with letters "a" and "b" in the "letter" column.

The result would look like this

```
xx <- tibble (letter = c (rep ("a", 3), rep ("b", 3), rep ("c", 3)),
              number = c (1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
              duplicated = c (rep (TRUE, 6), rep (FALSE, 3)) )
```

is there a way to do this elegantly in dplyr?

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
xx %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(number) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(duplicated = ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  select(-n)

      letter number duplicated
      <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>     
    1 a           1 TRUE      
    2 a           2 TRUE      
    3 a           3 TRUE      
    4 b           1 TRUE      
    5 b           2 TRUE      
    6 b           3 TRUE      
    7 c           4 FALSE     
    8 c           5 FALSE     
    9 c           6 FALSE
```

`distinct` is for if there are some duplicated inside of group,

```
xx <- tibble (letter = c (rep ("a", 4), rep ("b", 3), rep ("c", 3)),
              number = c (1,1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6))
   letter number
   <chr>   <dbl>
 1 a           1
 2 a           1
 3 a           2
 4 a           3
 5 b           1
 6 b           2
 7 b           3
 8 c           4
 9 c           4
10 c           6
    xxx <- xx %>%
      distinct() %>%
      group_by(number) %>%
      mutate(n = n()) %>%
      mutate(duplicated = ifelse(n>1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
      select(-n)

    xx %>% 
      full_join(xxx, by = c("letter", "number"))

   letter number duplicated
   <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>     
 1 a           1 TRUE      
 2 a           1 TRUE      
 3 a           2 TRUE      
 4 a           3 TRUE      
 5 b           1 TRUE      
 6 b           2 TRUE      
 7 b           3 TRUE      
 8 c           4 FALSE     
 9 c           4 FALSE     
10 c           6 FALSE
```

## Thanks to @LMc

```
xxx <- xx %>%
  distinct() %>%
  add_count(number) %>%
  mutate(duplicated = n> 1) %>%
  select(-n)
xxx
xx %>% 
  full_join(xxx, by = c("letter", "number"))
```

Comment: You can simplify further by replacing `group_by(number) %>% mutate(n = n())` with `add_count(number)`.

Comment: Also you don't need to use `ifelse` since `n>1` is a vectorized operation that returns a logical vector.

Comment: @LMc I always miss about that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cur_group()` to subset `xx` and test for containment:

```
library(dplyr)

xx %>% 
  group_by(letter) %>% 
  mutate(duplicated = number %in% xx$number[!xx$letter %in% cur_group()]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

1. `cur_group()` represents the value of the current grouping variable (eg `a`, `b`, `c`).
2. We use the value of `cur_group()` to subset the vector `xx$number` for those that are *not* part of the current group (`!xx$letter %in% cur_group()`).
3. Lastly, we check if the current group `number` is in that subset (`number %in% ...`).

**Output**

```
  letter number duplicated
  <chr>   <dbl> <lgl>     
1 a           1 TRUE      
2 a           2 TRUE      
3 a           3 TRUE      
4 b           1 TRUE      
5 b           2 TRUE      
6 b           3 TRUE      
7 c           4 FALSE     
8 c           5 FALSE     
9 c           6 FALSE
```